# Sum of eigenspaces is direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, direct-sum

I know, thanks to [a kind user](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022082/ab-ba-with-same-eigenvector-matrix/1022156#1022156) of this forum, that the sum of the eigenspaces of an endomorphism $A:V\to V$, with $\dim(V)=n$, is a direct sum.

A clear complete proof for the case where the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40966/finite-sum-of-eigenspaces-with-distinct-eigenvalues-is-a-direct-sum/40986), for example.

I cannot manage to adapt that proof to the general case where $A$ may have eigenvalues of algebraic multiplicity $>1$. Could anybody explain a proof?

Comment: The eigenspace of an eigenvalue is completely unrelated to the algebraic multiplicity of that eigenvalue. If the eigenvalue is $\lambda$, the eigenspace is $ker(\lambda I - A)$ where $I$ denotes the $n\times n$ identity matrix. The algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ isn't used anywhere in this construction.

Comment: That's what I missed: the eigenspace of $\lambda_i$ is the space $V_{\lambda_i}$ such that $AV_{\lambda_i}=\lambda_i V_{\lambda_i}$, but if the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ is $>1$, the eigenspace is still one! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_p$ the distinct eigenvalues of $A$ then since the polynomials $x-\lambda_k$ are $2$ by $2$ coprime then using the *[kernels decomposition theorem $^{(1)}$](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemme_des_noyaux)*
 we have that the sum of the eigenspaces of an endomorphism is  direct.

---

$^{(1)}$ This is a french page and the result given there is  a classic result but I didn't find the english translation of it and I'm not sure on what name this theorem is known in the English jargon.

Comment: Le français n'est pas un problème: lien très intéressant! !!!شكرا جزيلا

Comment: C'est tant mieux, profitez-en :-)