# Simultaneously diagonalizable without distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

It is a well known result that if $u$ and $v$ are two diagonalizable endomorphisms of a $\mathbb{C}$ finite-dimensional linear space $E$, if $u$ (or $v$) has *distinct* eigenvalues and if $u$ and $v$ commute, then $u$ and $v$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

I am wondering what happens when we drop the hypothesis that $u$ or $v$ has distinct eigenvalues ? The usual proof consists in saying that if $(\lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{n})$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $u$ and $E_{i} = \mathrm{ker}(u- \lambda_{i} \mathrm{Id})$ then $g_{\vert E_{i}}$ (the endomorphism induced by $g$ on $E_{i}$) is diagonalizable. Then if $B_{i}$ is a basis of $E_{i}$ composed of eigenvectors for $g$, $(B_{1},\ldots,B_{n})$ is a basis of $E$ which diagonalize both $u$ and $v$.

What changes if the engenvalues are not distinct ?

Comment: Very interesting question! You can take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022082/ab-ba-with-same-eigenvector-matrix and add questions concerning what's explained there if something isn't clear to you.

Answer (score -1):

An n by n matrix is "diagonalizable" if and only if there are n independent Eigen**vectors**.  Two matrices are "simultaneously diagonalizable" if they have the **same** eigenvectors.  Distinct Eigen**values** are irrelevant.