# If $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then also $B\vec{v}$, when $AB = BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following problem:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $A$, $B$ be linear maps of $V$ into itself. Assume that $AB = BA$. Show that if $\vec{v}$ is an *eigenvector* of $A$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $B\vec{v}$ is an *eigenvector* of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ also if $B\vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$.

Now, I have to show that if $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then also $B\vec{v}$ with the same eigenvalue.

So I started by assuming $$A\vec{v} = \lambda \vec{v}$$
Then I multiplied both sides by $B$:

$$BA\vec{v} = B \lambda \vec{v}$$
Since $AB = BA$, then
$$A(B\vec{v}) = \lambda (B \vec{v})$$
Which should prove what I needed to prove.

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $Av=\lambda v$. Compute:
$$ A(Bv) = (AB)v = (BA)v = B(Av) = B(\lambda v) = \lambda(Bv), $$
so $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ if $Bv \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, that's the displayed line in Jyrki's answer given already [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022082/ab-ba-with-same-eigenvector-matrix).