# Eigenvector proof for commutating matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices such that $AB=BA$. Show that
>   $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvector.

I am not able to prove this. Can anyone help?

Comment: BTW A similar statement for Hilbertspaces is the reason for the Heisenberg uncertainty principle in QM, if I remember right.

Comment: What do you mean by "characteristic vector"?

Comment: Are $A,B$ normal matrices, i.e. does their EVD exist?

Comment: @Test123 Eigen vectors

Comment: @user218931 I don't understand the question. Do you mean if A and B have same eigen spaces?

Comment: I mean that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvector for $B$ and $V_\lambda = \{v\in \mathbb C^n\,|\, Bv = \lambda v\}$ is its eigenspace, then show that $A(V_\lambda) \subseteq V_\lambda$.

Comment: @user218931 No I haven't been able to show this

Comment: @user218931 What does the second line mean? Does it mean that eigen space of A is a subset of eigen space of B?

Comment: It means that $A$ applied to the eigenspace of $B$ lies in the eigenspace of $B$ (viewing $A$ as a linear map $\mathbb C^n\rightarrow \mathbb C^n$).

Comment: @user218931 What does "applied" mean?

Comment: Let $$A=B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$AB=BA$ with same eigenvector matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022082/ab-ba-with-same-eigenvector-matrix)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $B$ and $v\in V_\lambda$ an eigenvector i.e. $Bv=\lambda v$. Then, since $BA=AB$ we have:
$$
BAv=ABv=\lambda Av
$$
This implies that $Av$ is also an eigenvector of $B$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$, namely $Av\in V_\lambda$. We deduce that $A V_\lambda \subset V_\lambda$ which is what you are asking as mentioned in the comments (even though the post doesn't clearly mention this).

Comment: But how does this prove that Av is also an eigen vector of A?

Comment: @AnimeshTiwari $Av$ is an eigenvector of $B$, not $A$.

Comment: yes but one has to prove that A and B have a common eigen vector. Av is an eigen vector of B, but how is it an eigen vector of A as well?

Comment: @AnimeshTiwari Not true in general. Check the accepted answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022082/ab-ba-with-same-eigenvector-matrix
It's assumed though that $A,B$ are diagonalizable.

Comment: will go throught that. Thank you!